# Amazon Prime Video on Opera: DRM error

Tags: opera, drm

If I want to play videos from Amazon Prime Video in Opera (Version 56.0.3051.104) on Ubuntu, I'm getting the error that there's missing a component for DRM, but I can't find an option to activate the "Widevine Content Decryption Module", which is nessecary.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Similar question posted yesterday: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105574/firefox-opera-unable-to-play-drm-protected-content-on-amazon-prime-but-google-c, unfortunately, no solution yet.